# R Session Aborted When Reading Large Dataset

Tags: r, data.table, sparkr

I need to read ~20,000 csv files (~500GB), then filter the data and bind them together. My code works when I only read ~15,000 files, but it prompts 'R session aborted' when I read ~20,000 files.

```
memory.limit(80000)
ReadCustomer = function(x)
 fread(x, encoding = "UTF-8", select = c("customer_sysno", "event_cat2")) %>%
  filter(event_cat2 == "***") %>%
  select(customer_sysno) %>%
  rename(CustomerSysNo = customer_sysno) %>%
  mutate(CustomerSysNo = as.numeric(CustomerSysNo)) %>%
  filter(CustomerSysNo > 0)
CustomerData = rbindlist(lapply(FileList, ReadCustomer))
```

I tried replacing `fread(x, encoding = "UTF-8", select = c("customer_sysno", "event_cat2"))` by `spark_read_csv(sc, "Data", x)`, but sparkR still didn't work.
How can I read all the files? Will Rcpp help?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Rcpp so I am removing the `rcpp` tag.

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you ever able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many rows you get back from each file, you don't say?
You're essentially posing this problem as a straightforward filtering exercise; you want only the customer_sysno column where certain conditions are met. What you then want to do with this will influence whether you even want to merge them all together.

I propose opening an output file and appending each new output to it. Then you've got a local file containing all your desired customer_sysno values. You can then walk through or sample that as suits your use case.

If the rows where your event_cat2 condition is met is actually a small subset of each file, and each file is big, then another approach would be to readLine your way through them, maybe in conjunction with appending results to an output file. This is basically asking R to do a job like (g)awk is awesome at, so that might be a useful preprocessing step to get you the desired data.

Comment: Thank you. I get back about 10 rows from each file. I tried to append new output to a file, but the same problem exists - R session still aborted. The problem remains the same using readLines. I would tried (g)awk, but I'd like to ask for other solutions within R. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Is it always on trying to read the same file? (What happens if you try to read only that file?)